# C# DataTable -> Need to generate an ID based on the column values

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, c#-datatable

| Value | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| A |  |
| A |  |
| B |  |
| B |  |
| C |  |

Desired output

| Value | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

I need to create IDs based on grouping the value column. A single ID for all A's and then B's respectively.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If the values might fall between A-Z then consider the following done in a form but can be done where ever you want.

```
public class Replacement
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Form code

```
private void SetIdButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataTable = MockedDataTable();
    var items = ReplacementData;

    for (int index = 0; index < dataTable.Rows.Count; index++)
    {
        dataTable.Rows[index].SetField("ID",
            items.FirstOrDefault(replacement => 
                replacement.Value == dataTable.Rows[index].Field<string>("Value")).Index);
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(",", row.ItemArray)}");
    }
}

private static Replacement[] ReplacementData 
    => "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    .ToCharArray().Select((value, index) => new Replacement
    {
        Value = value.ToString(), 
        Index = index + 1
    })
    .ToArray();

private static DataTable MockedDataTable()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    dataTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

    dataTable.Rows.Add("A");
    dataTable.Rows.Add("A");
    dataTable.Rows.Add("A");
    dataTable.Rows.Add("B");
    dataTable.Rows.Add("B");
    dataTable.Rows.Add("C");
    dataTable.Rows.Add("D");
    
    return dataTable;
}
```

Output

```
A,1
A,1
A,1
B,2
B,2
C,3
D,4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a loop like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++){ 
    switch(dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString()){
        case "A" :
            dataTable.Rows[i][1] = 1;
        break;
        case "B" :
            dataTable.Rows[i][1] = 2;
        break;
        case "C" :
            dataTable.Rows[i][1] = 3;
        break;
      // other cases
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here dt is your datatable. Use a loop like this:

```
 int id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = id;
                    if (i != dt.Rows.Count && dt.Rows[i + 1]["Value"] != dt.Rows[i]["Value"])
                    {
                        id++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[i - 1]["Value"] == dt.Rows[i]["Value"])
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        id = id + 1;
                        dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = id;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a dictionary:

```cs
dictionary<string,int> record_dic = new dictionary<string,int>{{"A",1},{"B",2}};
```

Comment: This is for C#. Did you mean `Dictionary<string, int>`? You put `dictionary<string, int>`, which won't work in C#.